# Column/rows centered in screen, sorted from left to right. Responsive

Tags: css, sorting, rows, responsive

Im trying to make my column/rows to work the way I want them to do. I have four elements side by side, all in one row.
When the screen gets smaller and hits the element I want it to push it down to the next row. This works fine at the moment. The problem is after it pusches the element down to the next row it leaves a big empty white space after itself on the first row. Lets say I use Flex and Justify center, it would "recenter" and always keep the elements in the middle. This would apply to both rows, Which is good beacause it removes the empty white space that the element leaves behind itself on the first row when it gets pusched down to the second row. The problem is that now on the second row the element are in the middle. I want them to be sorted from left to right.

If I Flex Justify Start, they will be ordered from left to right, which is good. But here the problem is that when one of the elements gets pushed down it will leave that empty space after itself and nothing will be recentered.

Any thoughts?

Take care

Comment: No need for code. If you read my post you'll see what im trying to achive. If you have any solutions on how to build this structure im trying to build let me know

Answer (score 0):

The most accurate way to solve that could be this one:

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.flex-container{
    background: lightgrey;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%;
    /* Flexbox */
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content:  center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-item{
    background: red;
    border: 4px solid yellow;
    height: 180px;
    margin: 1rem 0;
    width: 30%;
}
```

The problem with this code is ur first and last flex-item per line are going to be next the main-start and main-end. To simulate they are centered, flex-container must have less than 100% of the width.